# D3 visibility - if statement

Tags: if-statement, d3.js, visibility

I have a function, which changes the visibility of an element, by clicking a button.

```
$<button class="pure-button pure-button-primary" title="convex-button" onclick= "convexHullvisibility()"><i>Convex Hull</i></button>$
```

Unfortunately, this function does not work and I think the problem is in **if statement**.

```
function convexHullvisibility(){

            if (hull.attr("visibility", "visible")){
                alert("1");
                hull.attr("visibility", "hidden");
            }
            else{
                alert("2");
                hull.attr("visibility", "visible");
            }
        }
```

The definition of hull is here

```
svg.append("rect")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height);

        var hull = svg.append("path")
                .attr("class", "hull")
                .attr("visibility", "visible");

        var vertices = [];

        function redraw() {
            hull.datum(d3.geom.hull(vertices)).attr("d", function (d) {
                return "M" + d.join("L") + "Z";
            });
        }
```

Any help with the if-statement??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two-argument `attr` is used to *set* attribute values, if you want to *test* them you need to use the single-argument form to get the value and test it with normal JS operators

```
if (hull.attr("visibility") == "visible"){
```